# How to sort from smallest to biggest with `tree` command line tool?

Tags: linux, command-line, sort, tree

Which option should be used with `tree` command line tool to get sort from biggest to smallest?

```
├── [4.0K]  types2
│   └── [ 116]  types2.go
├── [4.0K]  types3
│   ├── [ 689]  types3.go
│   └── [   0]  types3.go~
├── [4.0K]  web
│   ├── [ 149]  index.html
│   ├── [ 647]  web.go
│   └── [   0]  web.go~
├── [4.0K]  wordcount
│   ├── [ 996]  wordcount.go
│   └── [ 773]  wordcount.go~
└── [4.0K]  zero
   ├── [  97]  zero.go
   └── [5.8K]  zero.o
```

Comment: How do we know there is one? (I don't see one in the man page)

Comment: I do not know @JeffSchaller maybe a loop with that command to get that style in output I have scroll the man too and do not get interesting things for the moment and was thinking to create a loop with tree to get that.

Comment: You may find it easier to patch the tree tool to do it natively, or to write your own separate tree-like script/tool.

Comment: It seems that you are right @JeffSchaller

Comment: You may want to give `ncdu` a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the tree tool doesn't support sorting by size directly, you can still do it using [tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) and [sort.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)

You can use the following command to list all the files and their paths in the given folder and subfolders with their file size and then use the *sort* tool to sort them by the second column of *tree* output (that is these sizes, being the first column all the **[** symbols).
We use [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) here to filter just files with a given extension.

Here's the command:

```
tree -sifF /opt/aplicaciones/gio/ | grep -v '/$' | grep ".jar"  | sort -k2 -rn
```

Here's a sample output with a somewhat large quantity of files so you can see how it behaves:

```
[   89702805]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-1.jar
[   89511250]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-2_22_11_2022.jar
[   89508457]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-2.jar
[   89487284]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-2_backup.jar
[   73631126]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-3.jar
[   73416714]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-4.jar
[   72904056]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-5.jar
[   72870839]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-6.jar
[   72824807]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-7.jar
[   72822778]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-8.jar
[   72822392]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-9.jar
[   72822125]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-10.jar
[   72821288]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-11.jar
[   72808348]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-12.jar
[   72794504]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-13.jar
[   70309496]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-14.jar
[   70298847]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-15.jar
[   70286111]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-16.jar
[   70283872]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-17.jar
[   70281102]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-18.jar
[   70275702]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-19.jar
[   70274483]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-20.jar
[   70273588]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-21.jar
[   70273058]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-22.jar
[   70271031]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-23.jar
[   70265460]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-24.jar
[   70090818]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-25.jar
[   69510384]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-26.jar
[   68674140]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-27.jar
[   68367619]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-28.jar
[   65897101]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-29.jar
[   65011678]  /myapp/first_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-30.jar
[   65010373]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-31.jar
[   51954261]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-32__test.jar
[   48092911]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-32.jar
[   43081254]  /myapp/second_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-33.jar
[   23357588]  /myapp/third_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-34.jarA
[   23357588]  /myapp/third_folder/artifact/this-is-a-file-number-34.jar
```

Now, the explanation of the used options:

From the man, about **tree**:

- *-s* Print the size of each file in bytes along with the name.
- *-i* Makes tree not print the indentation lines, useful when used in conjunction with the -f option.
- *-f* Prints the full path prefix for each file.
- *-F* Append a '/' for directories, a '=' for socket files, a '*' for executable files and a '|' for FIFO's, as per ls -F

About **sort**:

- *-k* --key=POS1[,POS2] Start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line) *i.e. Just think about it as columns separated by whitespaces.*
- *-r* --reverse Reverse the result of comparisons
- *-n* --numeric-sort Compare according to string numerical value

Answer (score 1):

The [tree utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) does not currently support sorting by size.